# Replace Body with regex in Camel logs

Tags: java, regex, apache-camel

I want to Replace certain Strings with * in Camel logs,For that i am using the following code with regex which works fine:

```
.log("message body: ${body.replaceAll('<Name1>(?:.+?)</Name1>', '<Name1>*****</Name1>')}")
```

But when i want to replace only first 5 chars i am using following code:

```
.log("message body: ${body.replaceAll('<Name1>(.{1,5})(.*)</Name1>', '<Name1>*****$2</Name1>')}")
```

But is is giving me following error with Null pointer Exception:

[image]

Any help will be appreciated, Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html#_operator_support) you have to escape `}` with `\}`. Since we are using string we need to escape the `\` character as well resulting in `\\}`

**Example:**

```java
.log("message body: ${body.replaceAll('<Name1>(.{1,5\\})(.*)</Name1>', '<Name1>*****$2</Name1>')}")`
```

Alternative would be to use exchange property and `body().regexReplaceAll`

**Example:**

```java
from("direct:regexReplaceExample")
    .routeId("regexReplaceExample")
    .setBody(constant("<Name1>John Doe</Name1>"))
    .setProperty("replaced", body()
        .regexReplaceAll("<Name1>(.{1,5})(.*)</Name1>", "<Name1>*****$2</Name1>"))
    // prints <Name1>*****Doe</Name1>
    .log("${exchangeProperty.replaced}")
;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply,The alternative povided worked..Is there a way to use ${exchangeProperty.replaced} in .to() ,something like .to("log:${exchangeProperty.replaced}")

Comment: Yes you can use [toD](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/eips/toD-eip.html) for that. For example: `.toD("log:${exchangeProperty.replaced}")`

Comment: Hi @Pasi Österman ,How do i restrict .log("${exchangeProperty.replaced}") to display only 10000 chars?

Comment: Its type is string so you can do typical string manipulation for it.